# Debug core file with specific debug symbols using LLDB

Tags: macos, debugging, crash, lldb

I have a program built in both release and debug modes. The released binary of my program has been crashed on a user machine (let the sysroots be the same, for simplicity), so now I have got a core file from this user. I want to debug this core file on my macOS using LLDB.

Let's consider I have these files on my machine:

```
a.out
a.out.dSYM
user_core
program.c
```

Now I'm trying to open `user_core` using LLDB, but no debug info or sources are available:

```
$ lldb 
(lldb) target create --core user_core
Core file '~/user_core' (x86_64) was loaded.
(lldb) f
frame #0: 0x00000001023b4f77 a.out`main + 39
a.out`main:
->  0x1023b4f77 <+39>: xorl   %ecx, %ecx
    0x1023b4f79 <+41>: movl   %eax, -0xc(%rbp)
(lldb) image lookup -v --address 0x00000001023b4f77
      Address: a.out[0x0000000100003f77] (a.out.__TEXT.__text + 39)
      Summary: a.out`main + 39
       Module: file = "~/a.out", arch = "x86_64"
       Symbol: id = {0x00000002}, range = [0x00000001023b4f50-0x00000001023b4f84), name="main"
(lldb) image list
[  0] <...> 0x00000001023b1000 ~/a.out (0x00000001023b1000)
```

After executing `(lldb) target modules add ~/a.out`, I got:

```
[  0] <UUID #0> 0x00000001023b1000 ~/a.out (0x00000001023b1000)
...
[ 44] <UUID #44> a.out[0x0000000100000000] ~/a.out
      ~/a.out.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/a.out
```

As far as I understand, `a.out` has been loaded twice, but LLDB still ignores the debug symbols.

I have also tried these techniques, with no effect:

- Open a core file using `(lldb) target create a.out --symfile a.out.dSYM --core user_core`
- Execute `(lldb) settings set target.debug-file-search-paths .` before opening a core file
- Execute `(lldb) setting set target.exec-search-paths .` before opening a core file
- Execute `(lldb) target symbols add ~/a.out.dSYM`

So the question is how to properly debug a **core dump of release binary** with the specified debug symbols using LLDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give lldb both the binary image and the core file when doing core file debugging.  But unless the dSYM is in a different directory from the a.out (and that different location is somewhere that Spotlight isn't indexing), you should not need to pass the symfile.  So your first command in the list of things you tried while a bit redundant, should have worked.

Are you sure the a.out.dSYM you have actually matches your a.out binary?  When the dSYM is made, the UUID of the binary that it's made from gets copied into the dSYM, and lldb will only use debug information from a dSYM if it matches the UUID of the associated binary.

You can find the uuid's of a binary or of a dSYM by running the command:

$ dwarfdump -uuid

There isn't a way to force lldb to use the wrong dSYM for an executable.  There's such a low percentage chance that's going to do anything useful that there isn't an override.

Comment: Jim, thank you for the detailed answer! Your guess about the different UUID is absolutely right (as you might see, there were different `<UUID #0>` and `<UUID #44>` for the `a.out` binaries in my original post). So now I figured out that LLDB does not support using debug symbols of `binary #1` when opening a core dump of `binary #2`, even if both `binary #1` and `binary #2` were compiled from the same source code.

Comment: On macOS the UUID is a checksum of the original binary.  The checksum is fairly smart, and doesn't include the parts of the binary that are just timestamp information.  The design is supposed to produce the same UUID if the source files and compiler options are identical between the two builds.  That's pretty important for big build systems where you build the same thing over and over.  Having a smart UUID like this means you only need to archive products that are actually different.

Comment: But for instance if you change the Optimization level between two builds, the layout of the instructions is going to be totally different between the two binaries, the optimizer will even break up functions into separate helper functions, inline functions, etc.  So using the wrong one would just be confusing and not at all helpful.  There would be no benefit to supporting this.

Comment: please can we provide proper steps

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for.  The resolution of this question was "you can't use debug information from a 'debug build' to debug a 'release build' binary".  The instruction stream would be entirely different between the two, and even structure layouts could be different if you have debug specific types.  So the proper steps are "to debug a core file you have to use the executable & dSYM from the build that was running in the process that produced the core file".

Comment: The comments took a brief detour about finding dSYM's but that wasn't actually the issue here.  lldb found the dSYM but correctly rejected it because the dSYM didn't match the binary.